# Is it possible to change android package name and Application ID programatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is it possible to change android package name and Application ID programatically, if it is possible please let me know the procedure.

Comment: why you want to do this. However you can change it via gradle script.

Comment: some kind of external script would help, shell or python

Comment: @may Rest in  peace can yu hv some example  or tutorial links. It would be helpful for me

Comment: @killer I need to generate same app with different features for different users. So if I change it everytime from android studio in gradle.  It will take so much time and I dont wanna do that. If I can do it programatically, I will approach that way.

Comment: You can have a look at product flavours and generate the applicationId for different users

Answer (score -1):

Not possible to change application id or package name programmatically, because there are many references are exist that are very important to launch your application , in the device every application have unique package name and before installed application it is verify your package name otherwise app will not installed without that

Comment: This is not true. You can achieve it via gradle script/ product flavors

Comment: That is generate your build with the given flavors configuration that does not means that the main package of application will be changes